# how to get the value of a checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I get the id of the selected checkbox already tried in several ways and does not return values

```
<div class="form">
    <li id ='preg1'>¿Qué productos de belleza llevas siempre contigo?<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="hipster" >Bálsamo labial y sombra de un sólo tono.<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="rocker" >Delineador y esmalte en tonos obscuros.<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="chic" >El lipstick y las sombras que te quedan increíble y que jamás pasarán de moda. <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="junkie" >El último lanzamiento de tu marca favorita y el esmalte de uñas que está marcando tendencia<br>
    </li>
    <li id ='preg2'>¿Para una cita cuál es tu look favorito?<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="hipster">Skinny jeans, maquillaje natural y un accesorio que destaque.<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="rocker">Chamarra de piel y ojos smoky.<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="chic">Blusa con olanes y maquillaje en tonos pastel.<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="junkie">Con las últimas tendencias de pies a cabeza, tanto en outfit como maquillaje.<br>
    </li>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){ 
      var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
      $('#'+parent+' input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
      $(this).attr('checked', 'checked'); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QSTns/

Comment: Shouldn't you be using radio buttons? Also, do you want the value of the checked checkbox, or the ID of the parent? Your question seems to indicate contradicting things.

Comment: You can get it by calling `$(this).val()`

Comment: To clarify, you want the id of the <li> element that is the parent of the input checkbox. Your input elements don't have ids.

Comment: For the record, in my testing on the latest stable release of jQuery parent contains "preg1" or "preg2" and the checkbox is unchecked immediately which seems to be the intent of the code above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Traditionally, it's much easier to get an answer if you show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using radio buttons for this, as this is what they were designed for, and changing the expected behavior could be confusing and/or annoying to the user.

Now, if you're interested in getting the ID of the list item containing the checked checkbox (using your existing code), use this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#'+parent+' input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    console.log( $(this).parent().attr('id') ); // Gets the ID
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QSTns/1/)**

Comment: very good your code but I require to get the value of selected checkbox

Comment: `$(this).val()` does that.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/QSTns/2/) will be help you to understand better now